# using synchronized block inside run method works strange

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
package multithreading.concurrency.cp.bqueue;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Object> queue;

    private int priority;

    public Producer(int priority, BlockingQueue<Object> queue) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(priority);
                synchronized (this) {
                    queue.put("object");
                    System.out.println("put  " + queue.size());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Object> queue;

    private int priority;

    public Consumer(int priority, BlockingQueue<Object> queue) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(priority);
                synchronized (this) {
                    queue.take();
                    System.out.println("take " + queue.size());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ConsumerProducer {

    private static final int SHARED_BUFFER_CAPACITY = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlockingQueue<Object> sharedBuffer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>(SHARED_BUFFER_CAPACITY);

        new Thread(new Producer(200, sharedBuffer)).start();
        new Thread(new Producer(300, sharedBuffer)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(1000, sharedBuffer)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(1000, sharedBuffer)).start();
    }
}
```

Why do I get the output like the synchronized block inside run methods doesn't work:

```
take 9
put  10
take 9
take 9
put  10
put  10
take 9
put  10
take 9
put  10
take 9
take 8
```

?

Comment: use `wait` and `notify`

Comment: Posting a lot of code, its output along with a simple 'why?' is not a very constructive stackoverflow question.

Comment: a lot of code? are you serious? I have the unexpected behavior, that I can not understand, what can cause it

Comment: @user3218114 with a custom blocking queue it works good, if make output inside queue operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you synchronizing on 'this'? You are actually syncing on 4 different mutexes (the 'this' refers to the actual instance of the Producer or the Consumer).
Try using `synchronized(queue)`

Comment: because i need to synch console output with queue operations; in your case you will get deadlock

Comment: OK, got it... So why not do as I suggested and use offer() and poll() instead? You understand that the sync you did has not meaning, right?

Comment: if I put console output inside blocking queue - it works good, but I want to understand why synch block doesn't work inside run

Comment: It does, you just sync on 4 different mutexes and not on 1 as you should. The 'this' in the sync is referring 4 different instances.

Comment: it's exactly what I need - synch separately each queue operation and console output for it

Comment: Syncing is the operation of mutually excluding operations between threads. To do that you need to sync on the same mutex, otherwise you are not doing any synchronization. Every time you reach a sync(this) in your above code you actually going to get the mutex and execute the code inside the sync.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59045/discussion-between-shlomi33-and-barn-gumbl).